# Virtual Host forces to download files

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have been struggling with this for more than 5 hours now, and I can't seem to find the fix to my problem.
Basically, I set up virtual host on my Fedora Core server (on custom port 55555).
Any time I try to access php files by typing in browser  for example 111.111.111.111:55555/somefile.php browser forces this file to download. 
I want php files to be parsed.

The following is my httpd.conf appended part:

```
Listen 55555

<VirtualHost *:55555>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/"
    ServerName 111.111.111.111:55555
    CustomLog "/var/log/app/access.log" combined
    ErrorLog "/var/log/app/error.log"

    <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Anyone has clue why the php files are forced to download and how to parse them?

Well, the point is that when I set up domain under plesk php files are parsed without any problem.

In httpd.conf there are only 3 lines referring to php configuration:

```
DirectoryIndex at_domains_index.html index.html index.html.var index.shtml index.cfm index.php index.htm index

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

In conf.d folder in php.conf file I have the following content:

```
#
# PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language which attempts to make it
# easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages.
#

LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so

#
# Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php

#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php

#
# Uncomment the following line to allow PHP to pretty-print .phps
# files as PHP source code:
#
#AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Comment: You need to post more of your configuration file, like, the part that configures PHP.

Comment: is the same if you disable virtual hosts and use the apache default root?

Answer (score 1):

Fix the problem by enabling php modules. Here is how my Virtual Host configuration looks like:

```
Listen 55555

<VirtualHost *:55555>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/"
    ServerName 111.111.111.111:55555
    CustomLog "/var/log/app/access.log" combined
    ErrorLog "/var/log/app/error.log"

    <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app>
        <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
            php_admin_flag engine on
            php_admin_flag safe_mode on
            php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app:/tmp"
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            php_admin_flag engine on
            php_admin_flag safe_mode on
            php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app:/tmp"
        </IfModule>
        </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```